# Is there any way to set a generic root path for content in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have faced problem with accessing static files from wwwroot folder in ASP.NET Core application in release mode. I keep my static files in wwwroot folder and access them with a relative path, for example to access *wwwroot/images/test.png* for **src** attribute of **img** tag I specify */images/test.png* and the picture loads correctly in local IIS Express development mode.

Now I have created Website in IIS Manager (**TestWebsite**) and deployed my web application to it, and also I created Application pool in site (**TestApplicationPool**) so that it's hierarchy looks like this:

[image]

The problem I have faced is that after deploy my paths to static files has crashed and to access them I need to have */TestApplicationPool* before any path (for the example above, now I need to specify */TestApplicationPool/images/test.png* to access image). So my question is there any way we can configure ASP.NET application to always use current Application as content root path, so that we don't need to specify nothing in path except the path of static file relative to wwwroot folder?

I have tried to get application name from **ContentRootPath** variable of **IWebHostEnvironment** and insert it before the path to the static file and in this case everything works, but it is inconvenient to do this every time we need to load static file from wwwroot folder.

Comment: What is `TestApplicationPool` even for?  Application Pools are not created under the web site itself. Something is wrong here.

Comment: Based on the screenshot, TestApplicationPool is actually a virtual directory/application under the website, possibly tied to an application pool with the same name. Probably just unfortunate naming causing confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVC views or Razor pages you can use a tilde and slash (~/) prefix on the path to represent the web root (wwwroot by default) in most places in your cshtml views/pages.

For example:

```html
<img src="~/hello.jpg" />
```

This should translate to the correct path even when deployed under a virtual directory in IIS (like your example).

Relevant documentation about web root can be found here, and this mentions the ~/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows#web-root